# Trouble implementing nested submenus and options in Chess Bot UI on CodePen

Tags: javascript, html, css, chess, codepen

I am working on a Chess Bot project and struggling with the UI implementation in a CodePen project. Here is the link to the CodePen: https://codepen.io/tag4-21/pen/jOeojXW

The main issue I'm facing is with the submenus. Since I am using radio buttons, nesting items becomes complicated and messy. I have tried various approaches, but I can't seem to get the submenus to appear properly within the main menu, along with their respective options.

Here is the desired structure for the UI:

```
Main Menu: "Chess BOT"
Sub Menu for Main Menu: "Game Settings"
Enable auto run
Enable auto move
Enable Suboptimal Moves
Enable Random Time
Auto Next Game

Sub Menu for Main Menu: "Game Stats"
Total Games: 0
Total Won: 0
Your win probability is: %

Sub Menu for Main Menu: "Recommendations"
Recommended Move:
Suboptimal Move:

Sub Menu for Main Menu: "Timing"
Auto Run Delay (Seconds): "[Text Input]"
Minimum Time (Seconds): "[Text Input]"
Maximum Time (Seconds): "[Text Input]"

Sub Menu for Main Menu: "AI Strength"
Depth Strength: "[Slider ranging from a minimum of 0 and max of 20]"
Suboptimal Moves Percentage: "[Slider ranging from a minimum of 0 and max of 100]"

Sub Menu for Main Menu: "Debug Settings"
Enable Debug Mode
Start Next Game
Save Settings
Load Settings
```

I have tried multiple solutions, but none of them worked as expected. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to properly implement the nested submenus and options within the CodePen project.

Additionally, as a token of appreciation, I can offer access to the beta version of the chess bot for testing purposes.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How do you want the submenu to be displayed? next to the menu items. To do that you'll have to get the position of the selected menuitem, and display the corresponding menu at that location.

Comment: @UmbQbify I have updated the codepen link the issue im currently having is i need to fix the buttons/rounded corners/text leaving the are how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit the question itself, with an example of the problem